# INotifyPropertyChanged in nested object

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have 2 main classes. The first class represents a Cell that can have values X, O or Empty. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on this.

```
public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Symbol state;

    public Symbol State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            if (value == Symbol.X || value == Symbol.O)
                state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }

    public Cell()
    {
        state = Symbol.Empty;
    }

    public enum Symbol
    {
        X, O, Empty
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

The second class contains an object of this class and is also set as the datacontext for my main window.

```
public class Board
{  
    private Cell testCell;

    public Cell TestCell
    {
        get { return testCell; }
        set { testCell = value; }
    }

    public Board()
    {
        TestCell = new Cell();
    }

    public void Cell_Click(int cellNum)
    {
        TestCell.State = Cell.Symbol.O;
    }
}
```

In my mainwindow I have set the datacontext as board, and also contains a button_click function.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Board();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Board board = this.DataContext as Board;
        board.Cell_Click(cellNum);
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have bound to Cell object within board using a button style like this:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding TestCell, 
                                      Converter={StaticResource BGConverter}}"/>
```

BGConverter is a custom converter that accepts a Cell object and converts it into a Colors object. I believe I am indeed directly binding to an object that has INotify implemented, so there's no issue of nested objects. However the binding doesn't reflect changes when I click. When debugging, I found that PropertyChanged event is always null.

The closest answer I found for this is that the event will be subscribed to only if the class Cell is my datacontext. Atleast that's what I understood. How can I correct this problem?

Also I am fresh out of college, currently learning WPF on a new job, so any general recommendations are welcome too.
Thanks

Comment: The `TestCell` property is not implemented with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So the `Converter` won't be called to update the value. I don't think there is some ***reference relationship*** between the Button's Background and the `TestCell`. So changing any property of `TestCell` won't reflect some change to `Background`.

Comment: @KingKing: As the answerer below suggested, I tried implementing INotify on Board class too, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @KingKing: Found the solution. I had to bind to TestCell.State instead of TestCell. Your comment led me to this train of thought. Thanks :)

Comment: that means your `Converter` will accept a `Symbol` not a `Cell`. My suggestion should also work, you implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged for it ***but*** you should also raise PropertyChanged ***when you change the state*** (although the state is changed, but we should notify that the Cell is changed). Then it should work.

Comment: Tip: Only fire the PropertyChanged event when the actual value changes.

Comment: @KingKing: To propagate events like that I would have to write a listener in Board class in addition to implementing INotify right?

Comment: @diAblo something like that, listening to state change and notify that `TestCell` change. It's at least a quick fix for your current viewmodel.

Comment: @Maarten it depends on your opinion about when an object is changed. My opinion (at least in this case) is when one of the object's properties is changed, the whole object should be considered as changed. Like as when your style (hairstyle, gesture, characteristics...) is changed, we say you is changed to another person. At least firing `PropertyChanged` in this case is just a way to ***trigger the update***. You can see that in .NET, there are some cases the actual value of some property is not changed ***but*** the event `SomePropertyChanged` is still fired.

Comment: @Maarten the usage of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is mainly applied in XAML Binding. So we rarely add some code behind listening to some actual PropertyChanged of some property. Even when we do so, with our opinion about when the object is considered as changed, it's still OK. And finally (in case your opinion about object change is different), the problem is just some code sometimes running ***unnecessarily*** (because the actual change does not happen).

Comment: @diAblo you should still follow the @Maarten advice. You just need to create an appropritate ViewModel and all problem will be gone. Such as in case you want to update the `Background` when any properties of the `TestCell` are changed, you may be attempted to bind `Background` to `TestCell`. But in this case you should add some property (to the `Board` vm) called `TestCellProperties` (of some type which may keep some reference to `TestCell`), then listen to change of all `TestCell`'s properties and notify change of `TestCellProperties`. `Background` now will be bound to `TestCellProperties`.

Comment: @KingKing  I was wondering how to do this in a more MVVM way. Thank you very much for the advice. I just tried implementing it. Having some issues since in my actual scenario I am dealing with a collection of objects rather than a single object. Nevertheless, I'll figure it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply bind to TestCell.State instead of TestCell

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this myself, but I believe your data context needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well.
That is, your Board class needs to listen to the PropertyChanged event of the cells and fire its own PropertyChanged event when this happens.

Comment: I tried implementing it on the Board class and firing it when TestCell changed. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you make sure to pass "TestCell" as the name of the changed property when you call the OnPropertyChanged method of the Board?

Comment: Yes the passed name was correct. I did find the answer though. I had to bind to TestCell.State instead of TestCell :)